# JNS(Java Network Simulator) for implementing ns2

Tags: java, simulator, ns2

Does anybody know how to implement `ns2` in `java`. If it can be implemented, then can I get some tutorials regarding this topic?

I got many tutorials from the web regarding `ns2`, got many tutorials in languages like `Tcl(tickel)`, `C++` etc. I came to know that in `Java` there is a `Java Network Simulator` module which enhances the ns2 support.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to do the ns2 in Tcl, the ns is a network simulator interpretor. You can get refer the tutorials in the link below:

http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Eitan.Altman/ns.htm